# How to give color according to the percentage in Highchart - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highchart that I reconstruct after every click. Chart values are dynamically creating by query and I push them into a `Chartdata array`.

I want to give the yellow color to my biggest slice after every query result but the biggest value is changing every time in array index. How can I do it?

```
var chartDataArray = [
  {name:"A", y: 19},
  {name:"B", y: 49},
  {name:"C", y: 32}
];
```

I want to give yellow color to highest 'y' always.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie',
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'sfprodisplay',
      fontSize: '20px',
      left: '0',
      top: '0'
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
      return this.point.name + '<br/>% ' + Math.round(this.point.percentage) + '<br/>' + (this.point.custom ? this.point.custom : "")
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        //format: '% {point.percentage:.0f}<br/>{point.custom}',
        formatter: function () {
          return "% " + Math.round(this.point.percentage) + "<br/>" + (this.point.custom ? this.point.custom : this.point.name)
        },
        style: {
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: '',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: chartData
  }]
});
```

Comment: Can you make fiddle?

Comment: add ", color:'#ffff00'" to the highest point in your chartDataArray

Comment: I think it should be dynamic.

Comment: Sory I can't make jsfiddle right now. Yes the chart array is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can find the point with the highest value and update it within the `render` callback function:

```
var renderEnabled = true;

(...)    

events: {
  render: function() {
    if (renderEnabled) {
      var maxPoint;

      this.series[0].points.forEach(function(p) {
        if (!maxPoint || maxPoint.y < p.y) {
          maxPoint = p;
        }
      });

      renderEnabled = false; // update() calls render() - prevent infinite recursive loop by disabeling render
      maxPoint.update({
        color: 'yellow'
      });
      renderEnabled = true; // enable render() after update() is finished
    }
  }
}
```

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8ztqh0gw/

Every time you set a new data the `render` even fires.

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render
- http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point.html#update

Answer (score 0):

I solved by sorting array and push color to chartDataArray.

```
var colors = ['#ffc843', '#192126', '#474d51', '#757a7d', '#a3a6a8'];

function myFunction() {
    chartDataArray.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.y - a.y
    });
}
myFunction();

for (var c = 0; c < chartDataArray.length; c++) {
    chartDataArray[c].color = colors[c];
}
```